# Huge AS 3.0 Export Frame

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am creating a very simple flash animation with no code or complex effects, just text and simple tweens (Flash CS5) But I have problems reducing the size of my swf.

From the generated size report, it looks like it has to do with fonts and/or exported actionscript classes. The frame with AS 3.0 Classes is over 100K, and even though I am only using one fonts, the same characters are embedded/exported multiple times

My questions are: 
Do embedding of mixed TLF/Classic text (or mixing other text properties, spacing/kerning etc) require the same characters to be embedded twice?

Do text transformations on TLF text (rotation and different transformations not available in classic text) require embedding of ("internal") AS3 classes that will increase the size of the .swf? (even though none of these classes are explicitly used by me, there are no scripts in the fla project)

I have tried removing all the text instances one by one, and at one point, the swf is reduced to only 5-6K, but I am not able to pinpoint exactly what causes the ballooning of the swf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to adobe you do need to embed font characters twice for classic text and for TLF.

> You must create separate embedded font symbols for use in TLF and Classic text containers. The TLF (DF4) outline format is not available for PostScript Type 1 fonts. TLF (DF4) requires Flash Player version 10 or later.
>   [Flash CS5 Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSb03e830bd6f770ee21a3597d124daee0526-8000.html)

You don't need TLF to rotate or transform text. You only need to embed your font. Flash CS5 does that automatically if you apply some transform to your textfield, but you might need to specify other characters because it only embeds the ones that are in your textfield.

Using TLF will increase .swf size. Embedding entire fonts will too. Don't use TLF unless you really need to and embed only the characters you need.